# OpenSearch Cluster deployment in Kubernetes - Connection Refused Issue 9200 Port

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, containers, helm

I am running a Kubernetes cluster in AWS EC2 instances.
I have one master node (t2.2large EC2 Instance) and two worker nodes (t2.xlarge EC2 instance). I created the cluster using KubeADM. The cluster is running fine.

I need to setup OpenSearch Cluster and Dashboard in my Kubernetes cluster. I was following the official documentation: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/install-and-configure/install-opensearch/helm/

Once the OpenSearch cluster pods get created, they are in pending state and are not getting into running state.

[image]

When I described one of the pods, I am getting the below event logs:

> Events:
> Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
>
> ---
>
> Warning  FailedScheduling  41s   default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling..

When I checked the PersistentVolumeClaim, I am getting the below three PVCs and seems that they are in pending state.

[image]

When I describe the PVC, I am getting the below event log:

> Normal  FailedBinding  0s (x7 over 88s)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set.

And when I checked for any PersistentVolume, I am not seeing any.
The OpenSearch cluster was created using the HELM chart from the official documentation, and it seems that the associated PVs are not getting created. Then I manually created three PVs and attached them to the PVCs and the above error got resolved.

However, even after that I was facing some issues. It seems that the pods are in `CrashLoopBackOff` or `Error` state and they are in 0/1 state.

[image]

When I described one of the pods, I am getting the below error:

> Events:
> Type     Reason          Age                    From     Message
>
> ---
>
> Warning  Unhealthy       6m29s (x12 over 58m)   kubelet  Startup probe failed: dial tcp 10.1.0.18:9200: connect: connection refused
> Warning  BackOff         3m19s (x111 over 57m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container opensearch in pod opensearch-cluster-master-0_default(d7d9fdc6-88ec-47e5-9420-c9a8dacf9ae1)

Seems that the the pod is trying to communicate to a service serving port `9200` and there's a connection refused issue.
After checking the service, I am getting the below result:

[image]

Seems that the OpenSearch master-nodes(Actually pods) are trying to connect to `10.1.0.18:9200`, However, from the screen shot that I have attached, the Service ClusterIP of `opensearch-cluster-master` is `10.99.173.27` and it's serving port `9200`. That's one area where I am confused. Also, seems that there's no option in the values.yaml or CRD to specify the value of the clusterIP.

Below is the logs of one of the OpenSearch Master pod:

```
    Defaulted container "opensearch" out of: opensearch, fsgroup-volume (init)
Enabling execution of install_demo_configuration.sh for OpenSearch Security Plugin
**************************************************************************
** This tool will be deprecated in the next major release of OpenSearch **
** https://github.com/opensearch-project/security/issues/1755           **
**************************************************************************
OpenSearch Security Demo Installer
 ** Warning: Do not use on production or public reachable systems **
Basedir: /usr/share/opensearch
OpenSearch install type: rpm/deb on Amazon Linux release 2023 (Amazon Linux)
OpenSearch config dir: /usr/share/opensearch/config
OpenSearch config file: /usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch.yml
OpenSearch bin dir: /usr/share/opensearch/bin
OpenSearch plugins dir: /usr/share/opensearch/plugins
OpenSearch lib dir: /usr/share/opensearch/lib
Detected OpenSearch Version: x-content-2.11.0
Detected OpenSearch Security Version: 2.11.0.0

tee: /usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch.yml: Permission denied
Enabling OpenSearch Security Plugin
Enabling execution of OPENSEARCH_HOME/bin/opensearch-performance-analyzer/performance-analyzer-agent-cli for OpenSearch Performance Analyzer Plugin
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch (file:/usr/share/opensearch/lib/opensearch-2.11.0.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.opensearch.bootstrap.OpenSearch
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.opensearch.bootstrap.Security (file:/usr/share/opensearch/lib/opensearch-2.11.0.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.opensearch.bootstrap.Security
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
[2023-11-23T10:05:41,318][INFO ][o.o.n.Node               ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] version[2.11.0], pid[48], build[tar/4dcad6dd1fd45b6bd91f041a041829c8687278fa/    2023-10-13T02:55:55.511945994Z], OS[Linux/6.4.16-linuxkit/amd64], JVM[Eclipse Adoptium/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/17.0.8/17.0.8+7]
[2023-11-23T10:05:41,324][INFO ][o.o.n.Node               ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] JVM home [/usr/share/opensearch/jdk], using bundled JDK/JRE [true]
[2023-11-23T10:05:41,324][INFO ][o.o.n.Node               ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Dopensearch.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Dopensearch.    networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:    +ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.    numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, -Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:G1ReservePercent=25,     -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/opensearch-5367794133992170925, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/    hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory=org.    opensearch.secure_sm.SecuredForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, -Dclk.tck=100, -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true, -Djava.security.policy=/usr/share/opensearch/config/    opensearch-performance-analyzer/opensearch_security.policy, --add-opens=jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach=ALL-UNNAMED, -Dopensearch.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xmx512M,     -Xms512M, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=268435456, -Dopensearch.path.home=/usr/share/opensearch, -Dopensearch.path.conf=/usr/share/opensearch/config, -Dopensearch.distribution.    type=tar, -Dopensearch.bundled_jdk=true]
[2023-11-23T10:05:43,188][INFO ][o.o.s.s.t.SSLConfig      ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] SSL dual mode is disabled
[2023-11-23T10:05:43,189][INFO ][o.o.s.OpenSearchSecurityPlugin] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] OpenSearch Config path is /usr/share/opensearch/config
[2023-11-23T10:05:43,568][INFO ][o.o.s.s.DefaultSecurityKeyStore] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] JVM supports TLSv1.3
[2023-11-23T10:05:43,570][INFO ][o.o.s.s.DefaultSecurityKeyStore] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Config directory is /usr/share/opensearch/config/, from there the key- and     truststore files are resolved relatively
[2023-11-23T10:05:44,187][INFO ][o.o.s.s.DefaultSecurityKeyStore] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] TLS Transport Client Provider : JDK
[2023-11-23T10:05:44,188][INFO ][o.o.s.s.DefaultSecurityKeyStore] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] TLS Transport Server Provider : JDK
[2023-11-23T10:05:44,188][INFO ][o.o.s.s.DefaultSecurityKeyStore] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] TLS HTTP Provider             : JDK
[2023-11-23T10:05:44,188][INFO ][o.o.s.s.DefaultSecurityKeyStore] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Enabled TLS protocols for transport layer : [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
[2023-11-23T10:05:44,188][INFO ][o.o.s.s.DefaultSecurityKeyStore] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Enabled TLS protocols for HTTP layer      : [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
[2023-11-23T10:05:44,251][INFO ][o.o.s.OpenSearchSecurityPlugin] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Clustername: opensearch-cluster
[2023-11-23T10:05:44,261][WARN ][o.o.s.OpenSearchSecurityPlugin] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Directory /usr/share/opensearch/config has insecure file permissions (should be     0700)
[2023-11-23T10:05:44,262][WARN ][o.o.s.OpenSearchSecurityPlugin] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] File /usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch.yml has insecure file permissions     (should be 0600)
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,138][INFO ][o.o.p.c.c.PluginSettings ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Config: metricsLocation: /dev/shm/performanceanalyzer/, metricsDeletionInterval: 1,     httpsEnabled: false, cleanup-metrics-db-files: true, batch-metrics-retention-period-minutes: 7, rpc-port: 9650, webservice-port 9600
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,826][INFO ][o.o.i.r.ReindexPlugin    ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] ReindexPlugin reloadSPI called
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,827][INFO ][o.o.i.r.ReindexPlugin    ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Unable to find any implementation for RemoteReindexExtension
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,911][INFO ][o.o.j.JobSchedulerPlugin ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded scheduler extension: reports-scheduler, index: .opendistro-reports-definitions
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,917][INFO ][o.o.j.JobSchedulerPlugin ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded scheduler extension: opendistro_anomaly_detector, index: .    opendistro-anomaly-detector-jobs
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,918][INFO ][o.o.j.JobSchedulerPlugin ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded scheduler extension: opendistro-index-management, index: .    opendistro-ism-config
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,919][INFO ][o.o.j.JobSchedulerPlugin ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded scheduler extension: scheduler_geospatial_ip2geo_datasource, index: .    scheduler-geospatial-ip2geo-datasource
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,928][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,929][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,929][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [geo]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,929][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,929][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [ingest-geoip]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,930][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,930][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,930][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,930][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,933][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,933][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [opensearch-dashboards]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,933][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [parent-join]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,933][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [percolator]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,933][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,933][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [reindex]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,933][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [repository-url]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,933][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [search-pipeline-common]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,933][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [systemd]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,933][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,934][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-alerting]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,934][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-anomaly-detection]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,934][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-asynchronous-search]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,934][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-cross-cluster-replication]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,935][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-custom-codecs]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,935][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-geospatial]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,935][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-index-management]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,935][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-job-scheduler]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,935][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-knn]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,936][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-ml]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,936][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-neural-search]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,936][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-notifications]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,936][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-notifications-core]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,936][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-observability]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,936][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-performance-analyzer]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,936][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-reports-scheduler]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,937][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-security]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,937][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-security-analytics]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,937][INFO ][o.o.p.PluginsService     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] loaded plugin [opensearch-sql]
[2023-11-23T10:05:45,999][INFO ][o.o.s.OpenSearchSecurityPlugin] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Disabled https compression by default to mitigate BREACH attacks. You can     enable it by setting 'http.compression: true' in opensearch.yml
[2023-11-23T10:05:46,003][INFO ][o.o.e.ExtensionsManager  ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] ExtensionsManager initialized
[2023-11-23T10:05:46,025][INFO ][o.o.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/opensearch/data (/dev/vda1)]], net     usable_space [51.1gb], net total_space [58.3gb], types [ext4]
[2023-11-23T10:05:46,026][INFO ][o.o.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] heap size [512mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2023-11-23T10:05:46,034][DEPRECATION][o.o.d.c.n.DiscoveryNodeRole] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Assigning [master] role in setting [node.roles] is deprecated. To promote     inclusive language, please use [cluster_manager] role instead.
[2023-11-23T10:05:46,131][INFO ][o.o.n.Node               ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] node name [opensearch-cluster-master-0], node ID [FaICBDbARHSCjAtbEHwNug], cluster     name [opensearch-cluster], roles [ingest, remote_cluster_client, master, data]
[2023-11-23T10:05:49,157][DEPRECATION][o.o.d.c.s.Settings       ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] [index.store.hybrid.mmap.extensions] setting was deprecated in OpenSearch and     will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.
[2023-11-23T10:05:49,159][DEPRECATION][o.o.d.c.s.Settings       ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] [cluster.initial_master_nodes] setting was deprecated in OpenSearch and will     be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.
[2023-11-23T10:05:50,306][INFO ][o.o.n.p.NeuralSearch     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Registering hybrid query phase searcher with feature flag [plugins.neural_search.    hybrid_search_disabled]
[2023-11-23T10:05:50,652][WARN ][o.o.s.c.Salt             ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] If you plan to use field masking pls configure compliance salt e1ukloTsQlOgPquJ to     be a random string of 16 chars length identical on all nodes
[2023-11-23T10:05:50,703][INFO ][o.o.s.a.i.AuditLogImpl   ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Message routing enabled: true
[2023-11-23T10:05:50,751][INFO ][o.o.s.f.SecurityFilter   ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] <NONE> indices are made immutable.
[2023-11-23T10:05:51,283][INFO ][o.o.a.b.ADCircuitBreakerService] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Registered memory breaker.
[2023-11-23T10:05:51,850][INFO ][o.o.m.b.MLCircuitBreakerService] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Registered ML memory breaker.
[2023-11-23T10:05:51,851][INFO ][o.o.m.b.MLCircuitBreakerService] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Registered ML disk breaker.
[2023-11-23T10:05:51,851][INFO ][o.o.m.b.MLCircuitBreakerService] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Registered ML native memory breaker.
[2023-11-23T10:05:51,962][INFO ][o.r.Reflections          ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Reflections took 65 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 20 keys and 51 values 
[2023-11-23T10:05:52,075][WARN ][o.o.s.p.SQLPlugin        ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Master key is a required config for using create and update datasource APIs. Please     set plugins.query.datasources.encryption.masterkey config in opensearch.yml in all the cluster nodes. More details can be found here: https://github.com/opensearch-project/    sql/blob/main/docs/user/ppl/admin/datasources.rst#master-key-config-for-encrypting-credential-information
[2023-11-23T10:05:52,116][WARN ][o.o.s.p.SQLPlugin        ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Async Query APIs are disabled as plugins.query.executionengine.spark.config is not     configured properly in cluster settings. Please configure and restart the domain to enable Async Query APIs
[2023-11-23T10:05:52,767][INFO ][o.o.t.NettyAllocator     ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=unpooled,     suggested_max_allocation_size=256kb, factors={opensearch.unsafe.use_unpooled_allocator=null, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=1mb, heap_size=512mb}]
[2023-11-23T10:05:52,771][INFO ][o.o.s.s.t.SSLConfig      ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] SSL dual mode is disabled
[2023-11-23T10:05:52,894][INFO ][o.o.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2023-11-23T10:05:53,467][WARN ][o.o.g.DanglingIndicesState] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be     automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually
[2023-11-23T10:05:53,990][INFO ][o.o.p.h.c.PerformanceAnalyzerConfigAction] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] PerformanceAnalyzer Enabled: false
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,023][INFO ][o.o.n.Node               ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] initialized
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,023][INFO ][o.o.n.Node               ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] starting ...
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,052][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [windows_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,053][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [waf_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,053][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [vpcflow_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,054][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [test_windows_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,055][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [s3_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,055][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [others_web_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,056][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [others_proxy_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,057][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [others_macos_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,057][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [others_compliance_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,057][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [others_cloud_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,058][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [others_apt_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,058][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [others_application_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,059][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [okta_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,060][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [network_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,060][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [netflow_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,060][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [m365_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,061][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [linux_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,061][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [gworkspace_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,061][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [github_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,062][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [dns_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,062][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [cloudtrail_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,063][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [azure_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,063][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [apache_access_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,064][INFO ][o.o.s.l.BuiltinLogTypeLoader] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Loaded [ad_ldap_logtype.json] log type
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,166][INFO ][o.o.t.TransportService   ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] publish_address {10.1.0.18:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,169][INFO ][o.o.t.TransportService   ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] Remote clusters initialized successfully.
[2023-11-23T10:05:54,308][INFO ][o.o.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [opensearch-cluster-master-0] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
```

**Below is the configuration for the PVs:**

```
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-0-pv-2
  namespace: open-search
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
     namespace: open-search
     name: opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-0
  hostPath:
    path: "/data"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-1-pv-2
  namespace: open-search
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
     namespace: open-search
     name: opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-1
  hostPath:
    path: "/data"

--- 

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-2-pv-2
  namespace: open-search
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
     namespace: open-search
     name: opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-2
  hostPath:
    path: "/data"
```

**Below is the configuration for the PVCs (after running kubectl get pvc -n open-search opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-0 -o yaml) that got automatically created by HELM:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
  creationTimestamp: "2023-11-23T13:46:31Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: opensearch-cluster
    app.kubernetes.io/name: opensearch
  name: opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-0
  namespace: open-search
  resourceVersion: "2407225"
  uid: ba8243d4-d1d7-4d42-bb06-597d678f149c
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: opensearch-cluster-master-opensearch-cluster-master-0-pv
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  phase: Bound
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried with different types of Kubernetes clusters including Docker-For-Desktop, AKS, etc. Yet still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you share some more information with your settings for the PV/PVC? For example are you running on prem, in the cloud, what storage driver are you using, and what settings are you using?

I can tell you the failure to connect on 9200 is because it can’t mount the volume and the server isn’t started. Without seeing configs it would be hard to help.

Comment: Hi there. I have updated the question with the PVC and PV details as well. Please do check. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, I have setup everything in AWS. I have three AWS EC2s. One for the master node and the other two for the worker nodes. I have used KubeADM to setup the Kubernetes clusters.

Comment: I haven't setup any StorageClass or anything for the PV/PVC, should I setup any?

Comment: In the error log it says `[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @arjunbnair that will do it! Here is the documentation to resolve that issue. This will need to be deployed on all servers that may run OpenSearch. This should not have a negative effect on any other running services. It simply increases the number of memory handles a process can have. 

https://opensearch.org/docs/1.0/opensearch/install/important-settings/